# Setting number of executors in Jenkins using Groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to set the number of executors in Jenkins using Groovy. I've found a method hudson.model.Hudson.instance.setNumExecutors(int) but it doesn't seem to really work. The problem is that the modified value appears in the configuration panel after I run the Groovy script, but I have to click 'Save' in that panel to really have it changed.

Here's the code (executed as a build step with Jenkins Groovy plugin):

```
import hudson.model.*

// Initial number of executors is 1, let's increase the number of executors to 2
Hudson hudson = Hudson.getInstance()
hudson.setNumExecutors(2)
hudson.save()

def job = hudson.getJob("some_other_job")
def future = job.scheduleBuild2(0, new Cause.UpstreamCause(build))
subBuild = future.get()

// Set the number of executors back to 1
hudson.setNumExecutors(1)
hudson.save()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is to call `hudson.setNodes(hudson.getNodes())` after calling `setNumExecutors()`.

Answer (score 0):

If everything is working as you expect except you have to press the save button manually to make the changes stick then it sounds like you didn't call [save](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html#save%28%29) on your Jenkins instance after you made your changes.

Comment: That's what I thought initially, but I've tried calling save() and it doesn't change anything- I still see the same behavior.

Comment: Added the code. As you can see initially there is 1 executor, then I try to add a new executor to schedule a job on it. Since the new executor is not being added, the job scheduled in the script cannot start, so everything is blocked.

Comment: Calling `setNumExecutors` like that seems too easy. I suspect something else needs to happen, like creating a new executor on a specific computer. Also, this is a long shot, but you might try using `jenkins.model.Jenkins.getInstance()` instead of Hudson.

Comment: I've tried using `jenkins.model.Jenkins.getInstance()` already- no effect unfortunately. I've checked `setNumExecutors()` implementation and it actually calls `save()` internally after setting the new number of executors. Another possibility is that it's a bug...